# FileNotFoundError in unzipping python file

Tags: python-3.x

I need to automate some boring stuff , one of such is unzipping all zip file in the current directory

this is my code:

```
import os
import zipfile

directory = 'D:\\Python ds and alg by mostafa'
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if file.endswith('.zip'):
        zipfile.ZipFile(file).extractall(directory)
```

however when i run this code I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python Automation Files/extract_zip_files.py", line 7, in <module>
    zipfile.ZipFile(file).extractall(directory)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\zipfile.py", line 1247, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '08_Logical_and_physical_Data_Structures.zip'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you try to extract the file **'08_Logical_and_physical_Data_Structures.zip'** which is not located in the same folder as your script (because its in your directory you defined). So you find it while you search for it (because here you search in the correct directory) but in the line where you try to extract it you dont tell python to extract the file which is located in the directory. So it should work if you change your code to:

```
import os
import zipfile

directory = 'D:\\Python ds and alg by mostafa'
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if file.endswith('.zip'):
        zipfile.ZipFile(directory + file).extractall(directory)
```

or to be safe you could use `os.path.join(directory, file)`

Edit: because I just saw it. You try to extract the file:

`D:/Python Automation Files/08_Logical_and_physical_Data_Structures.zip`

but your code should extract:

`D:\\Python ds and alg by mostafa\\08_Logical_and_physical_Data_Structures.zip`